# How to change response in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-response

I have RESTful service that is available by endpoints.

For example, I request `api/main` and get JSON data from server.

For response I use:

```
return response()->json(["categories" => $categories]);
```

How to control format of response passing parameter in URL?

As sample I need this: `api/main?format=json|html` that it will work for each `response` in controllers.

Comment: How would you format the response with `HTML`?

Comment: It should returns `View`

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried code that posted below

Comment: Have you thought about using Middleware?

Comment: How to use Middleware in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use for this [Response macros](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#response-macros). For example in `AppServiceProvider` inside `boot` method you can add:

```
\Response::macro('custom', function($view, $data) {
    if (\Request::input('format') == 'json') {
            return response()->json($data);
    }
    return view($view, $data);
});
```

and in your controller you can use now:

```
$data = [
   'key' => 'value',
];

return response()->custom('your.view', $data);
```

If you run now for example `GET /categories` you will get normal HTML page, but if you run `GET /categories?format=json` you will get Json response. However depending on your needs you might need to customize it much more to handle for example also redirects.

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to use `Middleware` for this. The below example assumes that you'll always be returning `view('...', [/* some data */])` i.e. a **view** with data.

When the "format" should be `json`, the below will return the data array passed to the view instead of the compiled view itself. You would then just apply this middleware to the routes that can have `json` and `html` returned.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    if ($request->input('format') === 'json') {
        $response->setContent(
            $response->getOriginalContent()->getData()
        );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your `format` query parameter example the controller code would look something like this:

```php
public function main(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'categories' => /* ... */
    ];

    if ($request->input('format') === 'json') {
        return response()->json(data);
    }

    return view('main', $data);
}
```

Alternatively you could simply check if the incoming request is an AJAX call via `$request->input('format') === 'json'` with [$request->ajax()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L213-L221)

Comment: Problem is that I dont want to write this code in each controller, I need DRY principle.

Comment: There's nothing stopping your from extracting the common logic into a helper method .

Comment: And as Ross suggested, you could return the`$data` array from the controller and let a custom middleware handle conversion to the correct type of response.